# Lack of context close as a sub-tree entry

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

So, I just hit 3k rep (yeah!)  so I dived into the 50+ entries in the closed vote queue.  Most of them fell under the "missing context" close vote,  which requires going to a second button push to get to.

Using the fact that the plural of anecdote is clearly data,    I'm going to assume that a large percentage of close votes here are due to lack of context.   (Correct me if I'm wrong).    It may not seem like much,  but to me it got somewhat annoying to have to go through two button pushes instead of one for each of these, trudging through bad questions...and then you multiply that by the number of other people who have to vote on each question,  those wasted seconds of all our lives add up!

So,  is there any way our kind administrators can move this seemingly highly used button to a primary (first page) reason to close,  so we can do it in one click?

Comment: Fun fact: On my screen, the action is at least only a double-click (no mouse movement involved in between). That makes it a whole lot less annoying :)

Answer (score 7):

Bad news: SE is not going to move that closing reason for us.

Good news: among my  [Bookmarklets for Stack Exchange](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC) there is one for that closing reason: it invokes it with  one click. Works in the Close review, too.

---

<sup>I also happen to think that this reason is getting a bit overused, while downvotes remain underused. Downvotes always take just one click.</sup>

Comment: The problem with downvotes is that they can mean a lot of different things. When someone complains about downvotes on meta, the first thing they are told is "don't mind the downvotes, they hardly mean anything", "don't take it personally, people downvote everything" and so on. So for recent questions, closing is still a better option.

Comment: It depends on the quantity somewhat. On [so], a homework dump typically gets 5-6 downvotes within a couple of minutes. This has greater effect than a single downvote followed by a sympathy upvote.

Comment: Yes, I wish terrible questions quickly got downvotes. But realistically it doesn't happen in general... Right now I just found two questions where the user literally posted a screenshot of their homework assignment, complete with the multiple choice radio button menu, one hour later they were still sitting around -1/-2 and one got an answer! At least voting to close pushes stuff to the review queue...